# Spring Cloud AWS code not finding S3 File

Tags: java, spring, amazon-s3

I do not understand why the Spring AWS Cloud code is not finding my S3 file.  I have the 'aws-context:context-resource-loader' in my spring bean xml configuration.  I would have thought the 's3:' resource usage would be seamless like spring the 'classpath:' resource is easy to use.

I know that the AWS permissions and credentials are configured correctly because I can retrieve the file in question if I use the       AmazonS3Client directly.

From the Spring [side](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-aws/spring-cloud-aws.html#_sdk_credentials_configuration) the AWS credentials should be found  automatically.

Here is the working Amazon S3 Client code:

```
public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException {
  AmazonS3 s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain());
  System.out.println(s3Client.doesObjectExist("MyBucket", "sample/resource.txt"));
  S3Object object = s3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest("MyBucket", "sample/resource.txt"));
  String result = StreamUtils.copyToString(object.getObjectContent(), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
  System.out.println(result);    
}
```

Here is the Spring Cloud AWS equivalent that is not finding the same S3 file:

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        final AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext("app-context.xml");
        ctx.scan("bdf.sample.spring");
        S3Resource s3Resource = ctx.getBean("S3Resource", S3Resource.class);
        InputStream resource = s3Resource.getResource("s3://MyBucket/sample/resource.txt");
        String result = StreamUtils.copyToString(resource, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

I have a System.out.println in the S3Resource constructor that shows this ResourceLoader:

> org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext

The Exception I get is:

> Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [s3://MyBucket/sample/resource.txt] cannot be opened because it does not exist

The S3Resource:

```
package bdf.sample.spring;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.core.io.ResourceLoader;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

@Service("S3Resource")
public class S3Resource  {
    private final ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

    @Autowired
    public S3Resource(ResourceLoader resourceLoader) {
        this.resourceLoader = resourceLoader;
        System.out.println(resourceLoader.getClass());
    }
    public InputStream getResource(String path) throws IOException {
        final Resource resource = resourceLoader.getResource(path);
        return resource.getInputStream();
    }
}
```

And finally my Spring XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:aws-context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cloud/aws/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/cloud/aws/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/cloud/spring-cloud-aws-context.xsd">

    <aws-context:context-resource-loader/>
    <aws-context:context-region region="us-east-1"/>
</beans>
```

github link with esentially the same code:  https://github.com/BDF/SpringCloudSample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue is that the ResoureLoader support for S3 isn't reading the region property.